# How to Integrate Test @RestControllerAdvice which Has Dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing, controller-advice

I have a simple `@RestController` in Spring Boot 2.1 which has a `@RestControllerAdvice` assigned to it to handle exceptions, e.g.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class MyController {

  @Value("${some.property}")
  private boolean flag;

  // Bunch of @Autowired dependencies

  @GetMapping(value="/to/load/{id}", ...)
  public MyObj getSomething(@PathVariable String id) throws MyException {
    if (flag) {
       // a dependency that throws MyException
    }
  }
}

@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = MyController.class)
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @Autowired
  private SomeComponent someComponent;

  @ExceptionHandler(value = { MyException.class })
  public ResponseEntity<Object> dealWithMyException(MyException exception) {
    SomeResponseObj obj = someComponent.createSomeResponseObj(exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus./*some status*/);
  }
}

public class SomeComponent {
  @Autowired
  private InnerDependency dep;
  /* other codes */
}
```

I have set my integration testing as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, MyExceptionHandler.class, SomeComponent.class, SomeComponentDependency.class})
public class MyControllerTest {

  @Autowired 
  private MyController mycontroller;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  /* MyController dependencies I need to invoke */

  public void happyPathTest() throws Exception {
    when(myControllerService.someMethod()).thenReturn("Something");

    mockMvc.perform(get(/* endpoint path */, "id1")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

  }

  @Test(expected = MyException.class)
  public void negativeTest() throws Exception {
    when(myControllerService.someMethod()).thenThrow(new MyException());

    mockMvc.perform(get(/* endpoint path */, "id1")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

  }
}
```

When I run a happy path test(s), everything works, but when I run the `negativeTest`, I get dependency error on `MyExceptionHandler.SomeComponent.dep` not being injected. As you can see, my integration test is employing `WebMvcTest` to tell the Spring about the context.

Also note that I am autowiring `MyController` since I need to use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set `flag` value for certain test scenarios.

I even added all the needed dependency classes to `@ContextConfiguration` at no avail.

How can I get around this dependency issue to get the controller advice to be called in such setup?

Also, how can I get the response body that the controller advice sends out to examine it's content?

UPDATE:

Using `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:149)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:395)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

If I add `MyController.class` to `@SpringBootTest`, I get the following (where is 406 status is coming from, and is Eclipse misbehaving here):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$$Lambda$268/2082545616.match(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at pkg.to.the.controller.MyControllerTest.happyPathTest(MyControllerTest.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection (or in the case of a real almost-always default like some flags, setter injection with a default value).